# Javascript promises: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm new to Javascript Promises. I'm trying to perform a MySQL query in Promises based style I've been scratching my head for over half an hour but I still can't find the problem in this code. I'm using [this article](https://codeburst.io/node-js-mysql-and-promises-4c3be599909b) as a reference.

**mysql file**

```
const mysql = require('mysql')
const Config = require('./Config.js');

let connection = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: Config.mysql.connectionLimit,
    host:   Config.mysql.host,
    user: Config.mysql.user,
    password: Config.mysql.password,
    database: Config.mysql.database,
    multipleStatements: true,
});

module.exports = {
    query: function(query, binds) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
            connection.query(query, binds, (error, ret)=>{
                if(error)
                    return reject(error);
                else
                    resolve(ret);
            })
        })
    },

    close: function() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
            connection.end((error)=>{
                if(error)
                    return reject(error);
                else
                    resolve();
            });
        });
    }
}
```

**actual script**

```
const Mysql = require('mysql file');

try {

Mysql.query("SELECT `password` \
            FROM `m_users` \
            WHERE `email` = ?", 
            ['user@domain.tld'])
    .then(ret=>{
        if(ret.email)
            return res.send({
                params: req.body,
                message: 'Email address has already been taken.',
            })
    })
    .catch(error=>{
        throw error;

    })

catch( e )
{
    console.log(e); // is never reached
}
```

`throw error` is never fired. Instead in my node console I receive the following error:

> (node:8684) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE: Table 'forge.m_users' doesn't exist
>
> ........backtrace here .......
>
> (node:8684) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)

I know the table does not exist. I'm interested in finding out why `.catch` does not handle the error. What am I doing wrong? :/

Comment: `throw error is never fired` Are you sure? That statement *will* create an unhandled rejection. Double check to see if that line is running or not - put a `console.log` above it or something

Comment: You're right - it is fired. I'm lost; how should I handle the rejection? I already have a try/catch block wrapping my entire procedure (see updated answer)

Comment: @user8555937 - In a non-`async` function, `try`/`catch` can't catch promise rejections, because by the time the promise is rejected, execution has already left the `try` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an anti-pattern (but you're not *by far* the first person to do it!):

```
.catch(error=>{
    throw error;

})
```

What that says is "Create a new promise" (because `catch` creates a promise) "and if the original promise rejects, reject it with the exact same rejection reason (`error`)." So it's basically a no-op, it doesn't do anything. It's the promise equivalent of:

```
try {
    // something
} catch (error) {
    throw error;
}
```

Since it doesn't do anything, consider what the code looks like without it — the code is breaking one of the fundamental rules of promises, which is "handle rejections or pass the chain to something else that will." :-)

If you want to handle the rejection, don't `throw` from `catch`:

```
Mysql.query("SELECT `password` \
        FROM `m_users` \
        WHERE `email` = ?", 
        ['user@domain.tld'])
.then(ret=>{
    if(ret.email) {
        return res.send({
            params: req.body,
            message: 'Email address has already been taken.',
        });
    }
})
.catch(error=>{
    // Use `error` here without `throw`ing -- report it, put it in a log, etc.
});
```

In an update to the question you show that you have all of your code using the promises in a `try`/`catch`:

```
try {
    Mysql.query(/*...*/)
    .then(/*...*/)
    .catch(error=>{
        throw error;
    });
}
catch( e )
{
    console.log(e); // is never reached
}
```

In a non-`async` function, `try`/`catch` can't catch promise rejections, because by the time the promise is rejected, execution has already left the `try` block. When using promises directly, you use the `catch` method instead. Or you use `async` functions (more below).

---

Side note: Node.js has had support for `async` functions for a while now, which tend to be a bit simpler to write. Within an `async` function, your code could be:

```
// Within an `async` function
try {
    const ret = await Mysql.query("SELECT `password` \
            FROM `m_users` \
            WHERE `email` = ?", 
            ['user@domain.tld']);
    if(ret.email) {
        return res.send({
            params: req.body,
            message: 'Email address has already been taken.',
        });
    }
} catch (error) {
    // Use `error` here without `throw`ing -- report it, put it in a log, etc.
}
```

[Using `async` at the top level of a module](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await) is coming soon, too...

---

In a comment you've asked:

> I'm building an MVC API and I run more promise-based procedures in the same controller method. I'd like to return a message once an exception has been encountered and stop continuing the execution of the next other promised-based procedures. I'm bound to using async/await method or is there another way?

You don't have to use `async`/`await` if you don't want to, no; they just make things simpler (in my view).

If you don't want to use `async`/`await`, in the fulfillment callback you're passing `then`, *return* the promise from the next operation. That makes the promise `then` fulfill or reject based on what the promise frm the next operation does — in promise jargon, it *resolves* the promise from `then` *to* the one from the next operation.

Code is worth 1024 words, so:

```
doSomethingAsync()
.then(value => {
    // ...use `value`, then
    return doSomethingElseAsync();
})
.then(() => {
    // ...
    return doYetAnotherAsyncThing();
})
.catch(error => {
    // Handle/report error here
});
```

If any of the promises is rejected, any subsequent fulfillment handlers are skipped, and the rejection handler at the end (added via `catch`) is triggered.

That's roughly the promise version of this synchronous code:

```
try {
    const value = doSomethingSync();
    // ...use `value`, then
    doSomethingElseSync();
    // ...
    doYetAnotherSyncThing();
} catch (error) {
    // Handle/report error here
}
```

Comment: FWIW, my new book will be out in a couple of months. I go into promises in some detail in Chapter 8 (and `async` functions in Chapter 9). See my profile for details.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I come from PHP background. I'm building an MVC API and I run more promise-based procedures in the same controller method. I'd like to return a message once an exception has been encountered and stop continuing the execution of the next other promised-based procedures.  I'm bound to using `async/await` method or is there another way?

Comment: @user8555937 - I've added to the end of the answer to answer that. :-) Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you all for replies, they're much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

basically, the reason you're getting an unhandled rejection is mixing async and sync code - promises are asynchronous and `try{ ... } catch() { ... }` only work in the synchronous mode. calling an asynchronous function in a synchronous try-catch block does not wait for it to settle. try to wrap your promise with `async/await` or handle the rejection in `.catch()` of the promise itself.